# T-SQL Projection/Forecast/Calculation Questions with CTE based on datetime and uniqueness

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Long time lurker, first time poster, I've been trying to solve this problem for the past couple of weeks and it's to the point where it's driving me a bit banana's.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_tbl](
[Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[src_Amount] [float] NULL,
[src_FullDate] [date] NULL,
[src_ProjectedFromhRate] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[project_AgainstRate] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[ProjectedDate] [date] NULL,
[ProjectedAmount] [float] NULL)
```

The table is filled with information like this:

```
INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES ('Company 1', '2500', '2014-12-31', '0.0010', '-0.0050', '2015-01-31', '2487.50')
INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES ('Company 1', '2600', '2014-12-31', '0.0020', '-0.0060', '2015-01-31', '2584.40')
INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES ('Company 1', '2650', '2014-12-31', '0.0030', '-0.0070', '2015-01-31', '2631.45')
INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES ('Company 2', '2500', '2014-12-31', '0.0010', '-0.0050', '2015-01-31', '2487.50')
INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES ('Company 2', '2600', '2014-12-31', '0.0020', '-0.0060', '2015-01-31', '2584.40')
INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES ('Company 2', '2650', '2014-12-31', '0.0030', '-0.0070', '2015-01-31', '2631.45')
```

I was able to use a recursive CTE to fill the table for every date between 2014-2018, meaning there's a row for each month(2015-2018) with everything else the same. What I'm trying to do is use a recursive CTE to calculate the amount for each date.

I want to calculate each ProjectedAmount for each month based on the previous month's ((prevProjecteddateMonth.projectedAmount*project_AgainstRate) + prevProjectedDateMonth.projectedAmount) = projected amount for each row from 2015 until 2018, for each company at each src_ProjectedFromRate and each project_AgainstRate.

I've only been able to get as far as generating the rate for February of that year so far, using various CTE's over the past two weeks, honestly it's been driving me a bit nuts, figured I would come and see if any of you could offer some help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show your CTE's, any other code you've selected; why it's not working, and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've spectacularly misunderstood (possible), I don't think you need a CTE at all.

```
select 
    Company,
    Src_Amount,
    src_ProjectedFromHRate,
    DATEADD(m, n.number, src_fulldate) as ProjectedDate,
    src_Amount * power(1+project_AgainstRate, number) as ProjectedValue
from test_tbl t,
    (Select * from master..spt_values where type='p' and number between 1 and 48) n
```

Comment: Wow holy crap, thanks bro, I think that did it for me, if your in NYC, please for the love of god let me buy you a beer one of these days.

I'm dissecting it and trying to understand it completely. Thank you so much again. I've never seen a comma in a from clause, I guess that just shows my lack of experience!

Comment: You could, in fact probably should, replace the comma with CROSS JOIN.  The comma is a bad old school habit I should get out of!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood the question correctly, but here's my stab at it:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8710/2

```
;with cte as
(
  select [Company]
  ,[src_Amount]
  ,[ProjectedDate] [src_FullDate]
  ,[src_ProjectedFromhRate]
  ,[project_AgainstRate]
  ,cast(DATEADD(d, -1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,[ProjectedDate]) + 2, 0)) as date) [ProjectedDate]
  ,[ProjectedAmount] 
  from test_tbl

  union all 

  select c.[Company]
  ,c.[src_Amount]
  ,c.[ProjectedDate]
  ,c.[src_ProjectedFromhRate]
  ,c.[project_AgainstRate]
  ,cast(DATEADD(d, -1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,c.[ProjectedDate]) + 2, 0)) as date)
  ,(c.[ProjectedAmount] * c.project_AgainstRate) + c.[ProjectedAmount] 
  from cte c
  where c.ProjectedDate < '2018-12-31'
)
insert test_tbl
select * 
from cte

select src_FullDate, Company, sum(ProjectedAmount) ProjectedAmount
from test_tbl
group by src_FullDate, Company
order by src_FullDate, Company
```

Comment: Hwy John,
I truly appreciate the attempt, although I think I explained it poorly. Will try to put up a sqlfiddle when I get home.

So, in my initial question, there are two companys, each company has about ~3 different projection rates each, so there are 6 unique rows. I was trying to figure out a way to do the calculation/projection for all unique rows (uniqueness being company + src_ProjectedFromhRate + project_AgainstRate).

Your projection/calculation is exactly what I'm looking for, just with n+1 individual rows based on the above uniqueness; so the same company but with different rates.